# Shadow variable re-calculation when tail leaves the chain

Tags: optaplanner

In our chain based (VRP-like) implementation. On specific entities, we have to use some data from n+1 in the chain, to calculate shadow variables of n.

With some careful calculation this works all good, until the tail leaves the chain, leaving such entity at the tail location.

Re-calculation would solve the issue, but it is never triggered, because n+1 entity is the one that is changed and re-calculated, so the old "left-over" chain is left in an inconsistent state.

Is there a way to manually trigger re-calculation for involved chains, even if `previousStandstill` did not change in any of the chain's entities, but in the ones that used to be there?

Comment: Have you tried the inverse relation shadow variable? (https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/shadow-variable/shadow-variable.html#bidirectionalVariable) What were the results?

Comment: I am using it, but it did not occur to me, to be able to use it as a trigger for re-calculation. Thanks! Will try to implement that

Comment: @LukášPetrovický, is it possible, that inverse shadow variable does not get triggered on `afterEntityRemoved`. The approach above works, but starts to run into inconsistencies when removing an entity in the CustomMove. It seems that removing an entity does not wake up inverseVariable listener. Probably for the same reason I notice, if I try to force it by also modifying the entity before removing it: `The fact X was never added to this ScoreDirector.`

Comment: I'd be very surprised if that was the case, but it can not be ruled out. If you can reproduce it with a minimal code example, please submit it in a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion from @Lukas was on the point.

I changed the `@PlanningVariableReference` from `previousStandstill` to `nextVisit` and then the listener gets called also when something moves from the tail.

```java
    @CustomShadowVariable(
            variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeVariableListener.class,
            sources = {
                    @PlanningVariableReference(
                            entityClass = Standstill.class,
                            variableName = "nextVisit"
                    ),
            }
    )
```

This allowed me, to properly re-calculate the chain on these occasions